OpenAI Assistant
Друзья! Нужна помощь. Уже долгое время рыскаю в интернете, все никак не могу внедрить ассистента в тг бота. В интернете все методы нерабочие и устаревшие. В самой документации OpenAi все непонятно, я уже запутался. Помогите пожалуйста. Мне нужен ассистент, который считывает из файла информацию.

Посмотрите этот проект. Вам потребуется использовать промпт-инженеринг, загнать в чат с нейронкой json схемы актуальных документов. Получить сами документы через словестный запрос, проще всего используя chromadb

Здравствуйте Петр! Спасибо большое за ответ. Вот только почему-то, когда открываю Index.html у меня показывает пустую белую страницу

@SwaGGerH1L Это приложение на NodeJS. Установите https://nodejs.org/, запустите npm install и npm start
